# How can I programmatically set the background color of a UILabel?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm programmatically creating some labels, but I can't seem to set their background color to black.  From what I read, it seems simple enough, here's my code...

```
UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height] autorelease];
[[lbl layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[lbl layer] setBorderWidth:1.0];
[[lbl layer] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[self view] addSubview:lbl];
```

When I do this, the border color and width work as expected, but the background color remains white.  Am I forgetting to do something?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A UILabel already has a `.backgroundColor` property, you don't need to tweak its layer...

```
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.  would you happen to know why the other approach doesn't work?

Comment: @Beach: No. Probably the label's backgroundColor is drawn above the layer, as you can reveal the layer's backgroundColor by setting the label's backgroundColor to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: It doesn't work because backgroundColor only accepts UIColor, not CGColor

Answer (score 0):

setting background color of UILabel

```
    [lbl.backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage        imageNamed:@"color_lightblue.png"]]];
```

setting TextColor of UILabel with image color

```
   [label_Description  setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"color_lightgray.png"]]];
```

simple background color

```
   lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 2

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

other formula:

```
       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height))

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = message
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use this

> `with one code you can set color`

LabelObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: What is so different to @kennytm's or Prasad Bulbule's answer??